# Vagrant / Git Bash : Window Freezes

Tags: vagrant, git-bash

I am attempting to learn a bit about the command line and am following a free online course.  I have been instructed to install a number of programs on my computer including VirtualBox, Vagrant and Git which I have done.  There was a VagrantFile which I have also downloaded.

The problem I have is that Git Bash is not responding to any vagrant command.  I am not familiar enough with the command line to test other programs or commands out but I have checked the Python version for example and got a response.

So when I attempt to run any vagrant command the interface returns the same location and then freezes.  I can click and highlight within the window but it will not take any keyboard input.  This happens regardless of whether I navigate to the vagrantfile folder or not.

Really confused! I have uninstalled and re-installed all the programs.

Currently operating:
Windows 10
Vagrant 1.9.7
Oracle VM VitualBox 5.1.26
Git 2.14.0

```
... MINGW64 ~
$ cd Desktop/Shell

... MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Shell
$ vagrant up

... MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Shell
$

// At this point the interface freezes and won't accept 
// any input.  It is the same if I call 
// vagrant init
// vagrant --version
// vagrant halt --force
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks Chris.

Comment: In a moment of frustration I hit a load of keys and got the response `bash: ... command not found`. It would appear that the git is receiving inputs still but it is not showing these when I type them!

Comment: *chris says: `Git Bash is not responding to any vagrant command`*. Why does git should respond for vagrant command. I could get your question clear.!

Comment: I have managed to run the code I need to in powershell which would suggest the issue is directly with Git.  Any tips or solutions for this?

Comment: @Haranadh I'm sorry I don't really understand your question.  A vagrant command appears to freeze git bash but this does not occur in other programs.